# Unable to remove top margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have menu :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" style="background-color:white">
    <ul class="sideMenu nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="dontHide"><a href="">Producers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Manufacturer">Producers</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sideMenu nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="dontHide"><a href="">Device library</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Device">Device list</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sideMenu nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="dontHide"><a href="">Device Instances</a></li>
        <li><a href="/DeviceInstance">Device instances</a></li>
        <li><a href="/DeviceInstance/Summary">Instances summary</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

And this menu looks like this:
[image]

As You can see with `hover` event the background color is changing with some margin betwen `UL` and `border-bottom` of the element before. I tried css:

```
.sidebar > ul{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.sidebar > ul:hover{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
.sidebar > ul> li > a{
    margin-top:0px
}
```

or
margin bottom:

```
.sidebar > ul> li > a{
    margin-bottom:0px
}
```

You can check this JSfiddle [CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/P8KTu/) when You will be able to see that margin I'm trying to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in 2 places:

```
.nav-sidebar{margin-bottom:0;}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.sidebar { 

padding: 0 20px;

}
}
```

so the code would be:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;

    padding: 0 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `margin-bottom` from your `.nav-sidebar`

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav-sidebar{margin-bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.nav-sidebar{ margin-bottom:0 }` instead of `margin-bottom:-20px;`